# Apply BeautifulSoup function to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a Pandas DataFrame that I got from reading a csv, in that file there is HTML tags I want to remove. I want to remove the tags with BeautifulSoup because it is more reliable than using a simple regex like <.*?>.

I usually remove HTML tags from Strings by executing

```
text = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').get_text()
```

Now I want to do this with every element in my DataFrame, so I tried the following:

```
df.apply(lambda text: BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').get_text())
```

But that returns the following error:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index id')
```

Comment: `print(df.head())` and `print(df.columns)`, what do they say? Your question cannot be solved without this information.

Comment: @coldspeed I am not comfortable copying the exact texts but its basically as follows: head shows several of the elements in my 11558 x 225 DataFrame, some of them are texts and some of them are numbers such as IDs, columns shows the names of my columns: id, title, text and so on

Answer (score 5):

Use `applymap`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["<a>Hello</a>"], "b":["<c>World</c>"]})
print(df.applymap(lambda text: BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').get_text()))
```

**Output:**

```
       a      b
0  Hello  World
```

**[MoreInfo](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)**

Comment: Then I get the error TypeError: ("object of type 'int' has no len()", 'occurred at index id'), I think it might be because pandas treats some text inside my data frame as an int instead of a string, any idea how to work around this?

Comment: @n.st `df.apply(str).applymap(lambda ...)`