# use beautifulsoup for content in dataframe pandas

Tags: dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a text file sent to me regularly with html content in one of the columns. I was hoping I can do a beautifulsoup against that column but seems like sources are limited out there.

sample.csv:

```
id web-scraper-order html_content
0  15636             <div class="product-details detail-row"><div c...
1  15619             <div class="product-details detail-row"><div c...
2  15656             <div class="product-details detail-column"><di...
```

Desired Output:

```
id web-scraper-order html_content                        html_content2
0  15636             <div class="product-details detail-row"><div c... ['EF1744','Grey Three/Off White/Gold Metallic','$120','2019-06-22']
1  15619             <div class="product-details detail-row"><div c...['...','...','...','...']
2  15656             <div class="product-details detail-column"><di...['...','...','...','...']
```

content in `html_content`

`<div class="product-details detail-row"><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Style</span></div><span> EF1744 </span></div><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Colorway</span></div><span> Grey Three/Off White/Gold Metallic </span></div><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Retail Price</span></div><span> $120 </span></div><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Release Date</span></div><span> 2019-06-22 </span></div></div>`

The text desired is below for each row:

`['EF1744','Grey Three/Off White/Gold Metallic','$120','2019-06-22']`

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189494/apply-beautifulsoup-function-to-pandas-dataframe) but does not seem to work with mine since I need to specify a column.

Very arrogantly I did this, but no luck....

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

d = pd.read_csv("sample.csv") 
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['web-scraper-order','html_content'])

soup = BeautifulSoup(df['html_content'],'xml')
style = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='detail')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `.detail > span`, which means select all `<span>` tags directly under any tag with class `detail`:

```
data = '''<div class="product-details detail-row"><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Style</span></div><span> EF1744 </span></div><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Colorway</span></div><span> Grey Three/Off White/Gold Metallic </span></div><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Retail Price</span></div><span> $120 </span></div><div class="detail"><div class="pinfo-container"><span class="icon"></span><span class="title">Release Date</span></div><span> 2019-06-22 </span></div></div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
l = [span.text.strip() for span in soup.select('.detail > span')]

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['EF1744', 'Grey Three/Off White/Gold Metallic', '$120', '2019-06-22']
```

Comment: Hi Andrej - sorry I forgot to put my desired output format. Please check my updated question above. Your result is great and it works fine, but I need those result in a new column extract row by row.

Comment: @Hachi I don't use Pandas so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Got it! But appreciate your help Andrej.

Comment: df['newColumn'] = [span.text.strip() for span in soup.select('.detail > span')]   maybe if same length as existing df index?